# WinSCP General failure uploading

Tags: upload, winscp

I am trying to successfully upload a Multi Drupal site source code onto my var/www/html/ directory.

So far, I have uploaded everything but the sites folder. When I do try to upload it, it gets up to about 70-75 percent and then prompts this error message:

> General failure (server should provide error description).
>   Error code: 4
>   Error message from server: Failure
>   Request code: 6

All of the folders have 755 rights and I am logged in as the root user in PuTTY.

This is especially frustrating because the file uploads for about 2 hours before it give me the error message.

I've a post that seemed to have the same issue as me but the person who had found the solution was not clear in their steps to fix the issue:
http://winscp.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1668

Here are the messages log since I could not locate the error logs:

```
Jul 29 13:54:16 ip sftp-server[4570]: error: process_write: write failed
Jul 29 13:54:16 ip sftp-server[4570]: error: process_write: write failed
Jul 29 13:54:16 ip sftp-server[4570]: error: process_write: write failed
Jul 29 13:54:16 ip sftp-server[4570]: error: process_write: write failed
```

Any ideas on what the problem could be?

Thanks,

Comment: What do the logs say?

Comment: Jul 29 13:54:16 ip sftp-server[4570]: error: process_write: write failed
Jul 29 13:54:16 ip sftp-server[4570]: error: process_write: write failed
Jul 29 13:54:16 ip sftp-server[4570]: error: process_write: write failed
Jul 29 13:54:16 ip sftp-server[4570]: error: process_write: write failed

Here are the messages log since I could not locate an error log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that the reason I was receiving this error was that I did not have enough disk space to upload all the files onto the Linux Server. My server having 8gb and the Folder being 8.60gb caused this error.

I used this command to check the disk space: 
df -H

Then I increased my EC2 instances disk space to solve the issue.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error message, I verified that the disk/filesystem has enough space. But it was different issue in my case.

I had to change the **resource limits** for a particular user.

"file size" value

Then it worked.

Comment: Specifically how did you change the file size limit for a particular user?

Comment: This answer doesn't really contain a proper description of the solution. How does one go about finding the 'resource limits'?

Answer (score 0):

The *"Failure"* is an error message for error code 4, returned by the OpenSSH SFTP server for various problems, for which there's no more specific code in the SFTP protocol version 3. While the server should at least return a specific plain-text error message, it fails to do so.

Common reasons you may get the generic "Failure" error message, while uploading are:

- Uploading a file to a full filesystem (HDD).
- Exceeding a user disk quota.

For details, see [SFTP Status/Error Code 4 (Failure)](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/sftp_codes#code_4).